# How to update samsung's SSD firmware?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, ssd, firmware

I'm having problems with my SSD (samsung 850 PRO) on linux so I wanted to update the firmware. I reinstalled windows and downloaded the magician software. It recognizes my SSD, I can run some benchmarks, but there's a message saying "this drive is not supported".

I've then gone into the samsung's website to download the firmware updater. It gives me an ISO file that I should burn using uNetBooting onto a pen drive (it says that this is a firmware update through windows, but it actually is a linux image that will run in the pen drive and do the update, I guess).

Anyways, I've burned the ISO into the pen drive and it didn't boot. I tried UEFI and non UEFI, but nothing happens.

I also tried to burn using dd, and it also didn't work (I didn't mess with the USB's partitions, filesystems etc though. Is there a needed one?)

Comment: I actually have a Samsung 850 Pro in one of my machines, and I am able to use Samsung Magician, to update the firmware.  Are you positive you have a compatible version of the software installed?  Can you provide links?  I would rather not have to go searching for links.

Comment: Could you verify that your drive is Samsung MZVLW(512|256|128)? I'm on windows 10 and my magician is 5.2.0. I also tried to install the 850 driver, which installed correctly. Here is the manual for the firmware tool: http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/FM/201710/20171030110819064/Samsung_SSD_Firmware_Update_Utility_User_Manual_English.pdf and I downloaded everything from here: http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/consumer/

Comment: @Ramhound I think I've mistaken. Here: http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/magician/ says that magician supports a lot of SSDs, but not mine (I thought it were a 850 pro, but mine is MZVLW512)

Comment: I know what SSD I have.

Comment: http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201801/20180123130636806/Samsung_Magician_5.2_Installation_Guide.pdf

Comment: http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201801/20180123130636806/Samsung_Magician_Installer.exe

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know how you got this 2018 link, because in samsung's website there's only the 2017. Anyway, are OEM SSDs updateable? Because mine is one

Comment: I searched for **850 Pro Samsung Magician** it was one of the first results.

Comment: @Ramhound installed. Still not supported. I guess there's no way to update OEM firmwares

Comment: Never done this from nix, but had to do it on a Mac. Had to reformat the SSD to NTFS before the updater would work [on a PC]... then back to HFS afterwards & copy all my data back.

Comment: @Tetsujin in my case it's a Windows so it's NTFS. But the problem is that the pen drive won't boot. Is it possible to update firmware on OEM SSD or not?

Comment: I did it by mounting it as a 'spare' blank internal drive on the PC & just ran the whole thing from Windows running off another drive. I don't remember any more detail than that, I'm afraid, it was some time ago.

Comment: Can it be done on Linux?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools.  Go to the "Samsung SSD Firmware" section. The links there to go to standalone ISO images which you can either burn to a CD/DVD, or convert into a bootable USB drive (by following the [Samsung firmware install guide](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/FM/201710/20171030110819064/Samsung_SSD_Firmware_Update_Utility_User_Manual_English.pdf) or using `unetbootin`). Make sure to choose the link that matches your drive!

Comment: unfortunately all available tools are build for x86_64 but my system runs on arm64/aarch64. Does anybody know a way to extract the firmware from these iso files and to update the ssd manually on linux having a non x68 cpu?

Comment: I don't think the actual binaries that Samsung provides for updating the firmware are open source so you only have x86 binary to actually talk to the drive firmware and that cannot be ported to other hardware architectures with sensible amount of work without the source code. The bootable ISO image is just a small x86 Linux live image running Samsung provided closed source user mode firmware updater program. Your best bet is to connect the drive to some x86 computer to upgrade the drive firmware.

Comment: that's what I also found out yesterday. I extracted the binary using cpio to see that it's a x86-64 binary:
`./fumagician: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, BuildID[sha1]`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same issues. Setting my BIOS "Boot mode" option to "Legacy" allowed my machine to boot the Samsung SSD firmware updater successfully. I changed the setting back after updating the firmware without any issues.

Comment: This worked for me although changing the BIOS setting resulted in warnings about the possibility of not being able to boot the OS afterwards. And even after I got the ISO to boot it didn't find my 870 EVO drives for some reason (or they didn't need an update?) Not a big fan of the Samsung software.