# How can I be confident that no new firmware exists for my SSD?

Tags: linux, ssd, lenovo-laptop, firmware, xubuntu

I'm trying to check if there is any new firmware for my 981 Samsung SSD, specifically a model MZVLB512HAJQ, that I installed in my Lenovo S340. This SSD was on the manufacture's comptatable parts list, but as I do not have Windows, I can not use the manufacturer's software to check for an upgrade. In fact, as this is an SSD that I installed, I would not trust the manufacturer's tools for this job anyway. I'm currently on Xubuntu 19.10.

This raises the question, **how do I check for new firmware in this case?** The links given in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1292332/865660) (linking to Samsung's websites) make no mention of the 981, a web search for '"MZVLB512HAJQ" firmware' finds no firmware, and Lenovo's websites seem to give me nothing even if I use the part number that they've game me for the SSD. Is this sufficient evidence that no upgrades exist?

Comment: I will delete my answer. There is no Software Updater for Linux and you would need a Samsumg tool for Linux to check the firmware.

Comment: You can run this to see version: `sudo nvme list` You probably have to install nvme-cli  For my 970 I was able to download the ISO and boot that to update it. Each ISO seemed to be just one version for one drive. https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/

Comment: @oldfred From ```sudo nvme list``` it seems that my version is "EXA7301Q". However, I don't know where to check that against.

Comment: My 970 NVMe drive is on Samsung's site for firmware update. But cannot find yours at all? It may be an OEM only part? You may have to ask Samsung directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general way one updates firmware on Linux is by using the `fwupdmgr` utility.  There is a Linux Vendor Firmware Service that it uses to find firmware compatible with your hardware.  The `fwupd` service can then queue the firmware for install using an appropriate means, restarting the computer if necessary.

That doesn't mean that Samsung is a part of the LVFS or that they've uploaded the latest firmware, but using `fwupdmgr` is usually the best and easiest way to find firmware updates for Linux boxes.  It is also more likely that Samsung contributes to the LVFS than that they built a custom tool for you to use.

Comment: Is it fair to assume that if ```fwupdmgr get-updates``` returns nothing, then there's nothing that fwupdmgr can offer me?

Comment: You may soon have SSD as an update option. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Fwupd-NVMe-SSD-Support-Start

Comment: Yes, that's a fair assumption.  In the latest versions, it will tell you whether you have the latest available firmware version or if there are no available firmware updates.

Comment: As of Jan 8 2021, Samsung has no firmwares in the LVFS.